# emulator crashing on wayland with flutter program

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, flutter-hotreload

Working on a flutter project with the Android emulator in Arch linux with swaywm (wayland), the emulator crashes on hot reloading.

```
emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_33 -gpu auto
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /opt/android-sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-dori/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/05-reset-dirs-sample.conf", line 6: unknown element "reset-dirs"
WARNING | cannot add library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
ERROR   | Failed to create Vulkan instance.
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 dori@unknown]
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_304417.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x2400, dpi: 420x420
INFO    | Boot completed in 22570 ms
INFO    | Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
INFO    | Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
[304421:304421:20230502,190903.999333:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190903.999505:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190903.999908:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190903.999992:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.000052:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002298:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002380:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002463:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002532:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002613:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002678:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002742:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[304421:304421:20230502,190904.002811:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  emulator -avd Pixel_6_API_33 -gpu auto
```

I can't make sense of the error and have no idea where to look at to try and fix this. Any idea what could be causing the crash ?

Comment: In the past, I had success with `-gpu host` instead of `-gpu auto`, but after an update I'm again stuck with exactly the above issue. In my eyes, it looks like a version mismatch between two libraries (one from android sdk and one from your os)

Comment: what you can try are options like `-no-qt` or `-no-audio` to isolate the problem. sure, it will not result in a working environment, but if it doesn't crash in windowless mode, you know it's about the ui. Right now, this is the only line which works for me (but I need Android studio to display it): `~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64 -netdelay none -netspeed full   -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 -qt-hide-window`